# How does PySpark work behind the scene when using a Python module which should load files?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have the two following python projects -

```
PROJECT A

class FeatureBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.artifact = read_artifacts_from_s3()

    def create_features(self):
        # do something with artifact
```

```
PROJECT B

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from builder import FeatureBuilder

def pandas_udf(df: DataFrame):
    feature_builder = FeatureBuilder()
    def create_features(pdf):
        feature_vector = fbuilder.create_features(pdf)
        return feature_vector

    return df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(create_features, df)
```

In this example, in project B, I'm calling to `create_features` function, which uses the `FeatureBuilder` object I imported from project A (which I can't change), and  `FeatureBuilder` reads the file it needs from S3 (or any other location).

Project A is not a "PySpark" project - by this I mean it has no code related to the PySpark package, Spark session or Spark context at all.

What will happen in this case? Will every machine in the cluster read the file from S3?

If yes and let's say I can change project A, is there any way to optimize it? Maybe load the file from project B, broadcast it, and pass it to the object in project A?
Or maybe can I broadcast the `FeatureBuilder` object itself?

I'm not sure what is the right way to do that **under the constraint that I can't add any Spark code to project A anyway**.

Answer (score 2):

When using PySpark, the code you write will be executed on a cluster of machines in a distributed manner. When you call the `create_features` function within the `pandas_udf` in Project B, PySpark will attempt to distribute the data and the code execution across multiple nodes in the cluster.

In the example you provided, when you call the `FeatureBuilder` object from Project A, the `read_artifacts_from_s3` method will be executed on each worker node in the cluster, causing each node to read the file from S3 independently. This can lead to a significant performance overhead and is not optimal.

If you can't change Project A, one way to optimize it would be to cache the contents of the file in memory on the driver node using the `broadcast` variable and then use it in the `create_features` method within Project B. This way, the contents of the file will be broadcast to all worker nodes in the cluster, and the data will only need to be read once.

Here's an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from builder import FeatureBuilder
from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast

def pandas_udf(df: DataFrame):
    artifact = read_artifacts_from_s3()
    broadcast_artifact = Broadcast(artifact)

    feature_builder = FeatureBuilder()
    def create_features(pdf):
        feature_vector = fbuilder.create_features(pdf, broadcast_artifact.value)
        return feature_vector

    return df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(create_features, df)
```